# C++ Creating a linked list using recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

Hi I am a beginner learning c++
I am trying to create a linked list using recursive function
I though I got more or less pointer, linked list, data structure etc but I am stuck for 2 days.

Here's my entire code.

What I am basically trying to do is like I said creating a linked list using only recursive function.
The problem is my pointer variable 'head' is always pointing to NULL and I can't figure out why and i guess i misunderstood a lot of things but i simply don't know what ... and more i try more i am getting confused.

It must be quite newbie question but Id really appreciate if someone can help me.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct linkedlist
{
    int value;
    linkedlist *next;
};

void insertNode(linkedlist* temp)
{
    if (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        insertNode(temp->next);
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = new linkedlist;
        temp->next->value = 0;
        temp->next->next = NULL;
    }

}


linkedlist *addNode(linkedlist *temp)
{ 
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        linkedlist *newelement = new linkedlist;
        newelement->value = 0;
        newelement->next = NULL;
        temp = newelement;

        return newelement;
    }
    else
    {
        insertNode(temp);
    }
}

void displaylist(linkedlist *temp)
{
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->value << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    linkedlist *head = NULL;

    linkedlist *element1 = addNode(head);
    linkedlist *element2 = addNode(head);
    linkedlist *element3 = addNode(head);
    linkedlist *element4 = addNode(head);
    linkedlist *element5 = addNode(head);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: what's the error you get ?

Comment: Please keep in mind, that recursion will cause strict size limits to your list. If you have too many elements in your list you will get a **StackOverflowException**. Consider avoiding recursion.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to modify the pointer you pass in to `addNode`, but the pointer is passed by-value, so you won't see the modification at the call site.

To fix this, take in the pointer by reference:

```
linkedlist *addNode(linkedlist*& temp)
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was missing that i couldnt find anywhere actually ... I am super beginner for now but i hope one day i can program like you !

Comment: It helped me a lot thank you so much . 
I would have eventually a question about this pointer by reference.

it solved perfectly my problem and I see that if i use this 'head' variable again on other function to print out my list it works fine.

My question is that how possibly this variable is pointing to starting element of list since i don't see any code making it point to it ...

Voila another very newbie question

Comment: (I wanted to enter to make space it just entered my comment)

I mean it's cool everything is working perfectly but i would like to know how it is pointing to starting element.

Comment: After all I was stuck in this chapter since at least 3 days actually you wouldn't know how much you helped me !
Thank you ^^ !

Comment: It is pointing to the beginning of the list, because the first call to `addNode` allocates a node into `head`, then subsequent calls append nodes onto the end of that node.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not make great sense. For example function `addNode` should have a parameter for the value that is added to the list. Also  there is no need to have two functions `addNode` and `insertNode` because they do the same (at least in your functions' implementations). If you want to have some function `insertNode` then it should have a different semantic.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how function `addNode` can be written. You can use it as a template for your program. In this demonstrative program function `displayList` is also recursive. Of course you need to write also the function that will delete all nodes. It also can be recursive.

```
#include <iostream>

struct linkedlist
{
    int value;
    linkedlist *next;
};

linkedlist * addNode( linkedlist *head, int value )
{
    return head == nullptr 
           ? ( new linkedlist { value, nullptr } )
           : ( head->next = addNode( head->next, value ), head );
}

void displayList( linkedlist *head )
{
    if ( head == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << head->value << ' ';
        displayList( head->next );
    }
}

int main()
{
    linkedlist *head = nullptr;

    for ( int x : { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 } ) head = addNode( head, x );
    displayList( head );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply !
I changed some of my code with your advice and actually yes i didnt need 2 function for 'addNode'.

Comment: But i haven't learned yet about some of codes you've written like nullptr and those below it like '?' and ':' but I really appreciate your advice.
I hope I could use your help again ^^

Comment: @Hwabum Kim You may substitute nullptr for NULL. As for ? and : then it is the so-called conditional operator. It is equivalent to the following statements if ( head == NULL ) { return new linkedlist { value, NULL }; } else { head->next = addNode( head->next, value ); return head; }